# Pulling all info from open Access subform into excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

We are using a access front end that is being developed externally. It displays a form that contains numerous points of data and a few subforms.

I am trying to code a excel sheet that would pull data from various places in the currently open form.

I have gotten as far as to be able to access all the points of data in the main form and the first line in the subforms using the following code (In this example, the "pnum", is the left most field displayed in the subform):

```
Set objacc = GetObject("xxxxx\Database.accdb").Application

Debug.Print objacc.Forms("mainform").Controls("main subform").Controls("Pnumber")
```

This works and gets me the value of the very first element named "Pnumber" in the main subform.

However, the way the subform is formulated, it can have anywhere between 1 and 30+ "Pnumber" fields.

I need a way to pull everything that the currently visible (filtered down) subform contains regardless of how many lines there are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I were the developer of that Access application, and you asked me for this feature, I would code an API for you to automate getting the right data.

One approach I can think of in this particular case would be to populate some temporary tables, on request from Excel VBA, and have Excel use the Access database file as an external source of data. Or Access could be coded to push the right data into the open Excel worksheet.

The way you would get access to the data in its current state in the form (filtered, sorted, etc.) would probably be best through the RecordsetClone property of that (sub)form. At least that's what I imagine I would use to implement that feature.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague made an MS Access form that talked to a database, and I needed to extract/copy/transfer the data in that form to my Excel file so I could work with it (reformat that data, combine with other data, send it to an API etc). His form had several controls (whose names & values I could get directly via accessObject.forms("nameofcolleaguesform").controls(i).name/value) and a subform (whose data I could only get for the first row [actually as it turned out later, the currently selected row, not the first] ).

What worked for me was to extract the RecordSet (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recordset) property of the Form and then iterate through all the rows in the subform with the Move command (.movefirst, .movenext):

```
Set rs = objAccess.Forms("nameofcolleaguesform").Controls("nameOfSubformControl").Form.Recordset

n = rs.RecordCount
```

then iterate over curRow = 1 to n, extracting all the Controls' names/values for each curRow (ie if you have 7 columns, then for each row you have a nested For loop from 1 to 7. after extracting all the controls' data for a given row, do:

```
rs.movenext
```

So, modifying OP's code with this RecordSet addition:

```
set rs = objacc.Forms("mainform").Controls("main subform").Form.RecordSet
rs.movefirst    'to make sure we're starting at the first row
            
n = rs.RecordCount
For curRow = 1 to n
        
    if curRow <> 1 then
        rs.movenext
    end if
        
    'extract current row's control(s)' names/values
    debug.print objacc.Forms("mainform").Controls("main subform").Controls("Pnumber")
        
    rs.movenext
next
```